# How can I convert json to a Laravel Eloquent Model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model-binding

if I have an Eloquent Model called Post, and the mysql table has:

integer ID,
string Text

How do I convert this JSon:

```
{ post: { text: 'my text' } }
```

To the relevant Post object that, once received in the controller,  I can save to the database like this:

```
public function store(Post $post)
{
    $post->save();
}
```

I'm not looking to build the logic that would do that for me, but for the Laravel way (or could it be that there isn't one? I googled it with no relevant results).

Comment: Have you fixed this?

Comment: Not yet, see comments on reply from @Bartłomiej Sobieszek

Answer (score 14):

1. Convert json to array
2. Hydrate model from array

   ```
   $data = '{  
               "unique_id_001":{"name":"John","email":"JD@stackoverflow.com"},
               "unique_id_002":{"name":"Ken","email":"Ken@stackoverflow.com"}
             }';
   $object = (array)json_decode($data);
   $collection = \App\User::hydrate($object);
   $collection = $collection->flatten();   // get rid of unique_id_XXX

   /*
       Collection {#236 ▼
         #items: array:2 [▼
           0 => User {#239 ▶}
           1 => User {#240 ▶}
         ]
       }
    */
   dd($collection);
   ```

Comment: I got the collection as you demonstrated, but I need Eloquent objects that I can save. For example like so:

$collection[0]->save();

Comment: I just had the same issue as Zephram, the Hydrate function works, but Hydrate is for importing arrays that came from the database and thus 'exist'. Calling Save on them will do nothing since they're not dirty: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14288

Comment: Instead of explicitly converting the object from `json_decode()` to an array, you can pass `true` as the second argument: `json_decode($data, true)`. Admittedly, it's not as clear what it's doing (how on Earth does `true` mean "array"?), but it does make the code a little more efficient.

Comment: You can make it clearer: ```json_decode($data, $array = true)```.

Answer (score 7):

`fill` looks like the method you want. To avoid adding every attribute to your `$filled` array, which you would need to do if you wanted to use the `fill` method, you can use [the `forceFill` method](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_forceFill).

It accepts an associative array of attributes, so the JSON will have to be decoded, and we'll have to get the inner `post` key:

```
$rawJson = "{ post: { text: 'my text' } }";
$decodedAsArray = json_decode($rawJson, true);
$innerPost = $decodedAsArray['post'];
```

Once we have the decoded data, we can create an instance of the `Post` eloquent model and call `forceFill` on it:

```
$post = new Post();
$post->forceFill($innerPost);
$post->save();
```

---

This is similar to doing:

```
$post = new Post();
foreach ($innerPost as $key => $value) {
    $post->$key = $value;
}
$post->save();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just turn it to array and fill an eloquent

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$post = new Post;
$post->fill($arr);
```

Comment: `Model::unguard()` before the `fill` will fill up every property.

Answer (score 4):

It's way simple as like followings:

```
$json_post = { "post": { "text": "my text" } };

$post = new Post(
    json_decode($json_post, true)
);
```

Now, you can run all eloquent methods on the most $post, ex:

```
$post->save()
```

I tested with laravel v7.11.0

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like this?

```
public function store($poststuff)
{
    $post = new Post;
    $post->text = $poststuff['text'];
    $post->save();
}
```

Comment: Yes but its not good enough because if I'm going to handle big objects it would mean lots of code for each one.

Comment: You do foreach to loop $poststuff

Comment: You're right, but this is more suitable for flat objects that don't have arrays or more objects inside them.

I could write logic to handle this, but as I mentioned in the original post - I'm looking for a laravel solution to this.

Comment: not sure of any laravel way but to do foreach stuff to a var, like $data, then array_push($list,$data).. Then afterwards do ->insert($list);

Answer (score 0):

JSON to model helper function

```
if (!function_exists('jsonToModel')) {
    function jsonToModel(string $jsonFilePath, Model $model)
    {
        $json = file_get_contents($jsonFilePath);
        $data = json_decode($json);

        foreach ($data as $value) {
            $value = (array) $value;
            $model->updateOrCreate(
                ['id' => $value['id']],
                $value
            );
        }
    }
}
```

use like this

```
jsonToModel(database_path('json/models.json'), new Model());
```