# How to create model, that get data from JSON?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

I have Http:get in controller:

```
class PostController extends Controller {

private $data;

public function __construct()
{
    $minutes = 5;
    $this->data = Cache::remember('posts', $minutes, function () {
        return Http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=20')->json();
    });
}

public function index() {
    $posts = $this->data; // i want this line like that: $posts = Post::all()
    return view('posts', compact('posts'));
}
}
```

How to get data out and create a separate model with this Http data?

Comment: Look at the repository pattern. I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Have a look at this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730920/how-can-i-convert-json-to-a-laravel-eloquent-model

Answer (score 0):

You should make a class based on the properties that exist on the data you've fetch form url.
So you can make an instance by passing your data to it:

```
$post = new Post();
$post->title = $post_fetched_from_url->title;

return $post;
```

the output would be like:

```
App\Models\Post {#3365
 title: "This is a title",
 ...
}
```

So this is an model instance that you made it **on fly** and its not stored in your DB.

Although you can loop on posts if you have more than one post.

**Updated**:
So your answer would be some thing like this:

```
$posts = Http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=20')->json();

$posts = collect($posts)->map(function($item) {
    $model = new Post();
    $model->user_id = $item['userId'];
    $model->id = $item['id'];
    $model->title = $item['title'];
    $model->body = $item['body'];
    return $model;
});

return dd($posts);
```

And this is the **output**:

[image]

Comment: I should do somthing like that $Post = new Post($this->data); in Controller?

Comment: Yes, but you can do it in model too but the easiest way is write it in your controller. I just **updated** my answer to clarify my meaning.

Comment: Can you explain more specifically? How do I get multiple records?

Comment: Program throw this error: 'Cannot use object of type GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response as array'

Comment: Be sure `$posts` returns an array. If it's not, convert it to an array.